# Is it OK to alter the original logo on dark background or it's not a best practice for Branding?

Tags: color, logo, branding

Like below. Or we should try to make the change the original logo so it can look identical on any background?

Can the 2nd logo (inverted) harm the branding or it's ok?

[image]

It's easy to inverse a single color logo. But how to invert multicolored logo for dark background?

Comment: YOUR logo or someone else's? If it's your logo, this decision is up to you. Many corporate logos come in variations to handle this exact situation. Some don't. If it's someone else's logo, then you need to check with their brand guidelines.

Answer (score 5):

It's not uncommon for companies to have a separate reversed/inverted logo for use on dark backgrounds. It does not go against best practices for branding to do so. As dezinezync points out, any decent branding guideline should specify how to handle it.

Rocky Mountain College's logo exemplifies this sort of practice:

[image: Rocky Mountain College logos]
<sup>Click image for full resolution. Source: [rocky.edu](http://www.rocky.edu/about-rocky/news-information/logo/)</sup>

Most notably, the shapes above the book are significantly changed. The bordering of the shield is also different.

If it's a logo that you are developing, it's perfectly fine to leave the logo unaltered for use on a dark background. The example you posted wouldn't be considered "wrong". However, another alternative for that logo would be to reverse the colors of the icon like so:

[image: Libre Office reversed logo mock-up]

However, as DA01 said in a comment, if it's not your logo then you should always check with the client to verify how to handle it.

Answer (score 2):

Most branding assets come with guidelines. They usually enlist do's and dont's. I'd recommend strictly following them.

Here's an example of twitter's guidelines. 
https://about.twitter.com/press/brand-assets

If the company in question does not provide such guidelines, I'd recommend sending them an email, along with the above image and ask them if it's okay. Get that in writing so you won'g have to deal with any problems from the legal department in the future.

Edit: Also, since you're trying to use it on a dark background, a monochromatic asset would suit best. Inverting the green wouldn't look too nice.

Edit 2: for a two/multi-color asset, the best example in my head was the Spotify logo. 
You can find various assets here http://press.spotify.com/us/2013/01/22/logotype/

As you can see, the company provides separate assets for light and dark backgrounds and various media types. If the company in question does not provide such assets, I'd say you're left with the email option.

Comment: I added this Libreoffice logo just to give an example. I have seen Branding guidelines of many company which has Default logo in single color. I'm searching in google for example of Multicolored logo inverse for a Brand

Comment: Updated my answer